# I get the following error message while I run the command ant CreateDb in cmd:

Tags: postgresql, ant, cmd

> FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

I use windows 7, in order to fix the problem, I modified the file pg_hba.cong from

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            CIDR-ADDRESS            METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

to the following:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            CIDR-ADDRESS            METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

then I use the same command but this time i get this error:

ERROR: language "plpgsql" already exists.

would someone please explain to me what the heck is wrong??

Comment: Could you be more specific, which statement do you use, did you create plpgsql language on this database before?

Comment: well, I am trying to run (ant createDb) in cmd so I could create a database which enables me to run startup.sh in cmd so at the end I can be able to access a web page at my local host. in order to get to the web page i have to run this command plus another one (ant deploy-war) in cmd. right now I am trying to create the database in cmd using the command ant createDb. however when I run the command i get this error: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres".

Comment: so i am looking or a way to figure out the problem and be able to solve it.

Comment: One more question - which product do you try to install? I think the problem should be in build.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error about the language plpgsql occurs because your script is trying to create the language but it is already available in the database. Either you should modify the script so it doesn't try to create the language, look for `CREATE LANGUAGE` or you could remove the language before hand from your database using `DROP LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

Comment: @Nima, that's highly unlikely. Where did you enter the command? Did you get an error if yes post the exact error message.

Comment: hey man, thank you for the advice, it worked perfectly! what I had to do use the DROP command in build.xml command instead of using it in cmd!

Answer (score 1):

`DROP EXTENSION plpgsql;`

psql version 9.1.7